# How to switch between two input lines based on a digital pulse

Tags: digital-logic, switches, multiplexer, switching

How can I switch between two inputs based on a digital signal. I would like to have the **Input 1** connected to the **Output** for the duration of the pulse and **Input 2** connected to **Output** when the signal goes low.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A simple analog mux will work. http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/ADG636.pdf

Comment: Your description is confusing, but I take it to mean that while the Signal is oscillating you want Input 1 to be connected to Output, and when it stops oscillating you want Input 1 to disconnected from Output and Input 2 to be connected to Output instead.  If that's right, how soon after Signal starts oscillating do you want Input 1 to be connected to Output, and how soon after it stops oscillating do you want Input 1 to be disconnected from Output and replaced by Input2?

Comment: @EMFields You are right. In less than 1 Micro Second of the start of signal oscillating, I want Input 1 connected to the output and 40 microseconds after the signal stops oscillating, I want the Input1 to be disconnected from output and replaced with Input2.

Comment: What kind of signals are Input 1 and Input 2 (analog? digital?  voltage? frequency?) and what do their sources and loads look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with 2 ICs and no MCU. I'm assuming you have 3.3 volts available for power, but 3 volts will work. You can use a 74HC4538 monostable multivibrator to detect your 1 MHz, and a 74HC157 to select your data. See http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT4538.pdf for the 74HC4538. A schematic looks like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBgN0t.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Please note that each IC has a bunch of unused inputs which you will need to tie to ground.

It works like this: every rising edge at the 1B input will cause 1Q to go high and stay there for 40 usec (0.7 x R x C = 0.7 x 56 x 1000 x 1 x 1000 psec). Since U1 is a retriggerable monostable, each succeeding edge will start the 40 usec period again without causing a glitch in the output. 40 usec after the last edge of the input, Q will return low. The high on the select line of U2 will cause signal B to be connected to the output during the burst. When SEL is low, signal A will be selected. Note that, unlike a 4066, the connection is not bidirectional. The selected input drives the output and not the other way, as with an analog gate. The turn-on delay from the first edge will be about 150 nsec for 3.3 volt operation.

Using a 5 volt supply will be a problem, since the input levels will be too low, but you can get away with using a 74HCT4538 and 74HCT157 in that case, although then the 157 outputs will try to drive to +5 as well.

If it's not obvious, you can select up to 4 pairs of signals with one 74HC157, although there is only a single select line for the entire chip.

ETA - when I did the schematic and above explanation I *completely forgot* that you had specified an analog gate. Doh!. Well, the 4538 part will still work just fine, and the output will drive a 4066. However, you should also be aware that a CD4066 http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4066b.pdf is only characterized for operation at 5, 10 and 15 volts. It will operate at 3.3, but see Fig 5, which suggests that the on-resistance at 3 volt operation will be somewhere in the vicinity of 1k (or more, maybe - it's just not specified.)

Answer (score 4):

You can switch between two outputs using a bilateral switch IC like the [CD4066](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4066b.pdf).

[image]
[image]

(Image source: [Practical Electronics/IC/4066](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Practical_Electronics/IC/4066))

If you have an MCU handy, you can use it to detect the pulse and to operate the switch. You'll have to use two out of the four switches on the 4066 to make one of your swithes. For example, attach **Input 1** to **pin 1**, **Input 2** to **pin 4** and **Output** to both **pins 2 and 3**. Then switch between the inputs using **pins 13 and 5**. You can operate both switch pins using 2 MCU GPIOs or you can place an inverter on one of them and use a single GPIO to operate the switch so that when pin 13 is high, pin 5 is low.

Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it with a retriggerable one-shot made from a couple of gates, and a couple of analog switches:

[image]

They're both available in TI's "tiny logic", so you can put together what you need with no leftovers.

The circuit might change depending on what you're trying to switch, so as soon as that info is forthcoming I'll edit my design, if necessary.

Also,there's some variation in the unit-to-unit '02 switching thresholds, so R5 should be a 10k pot wired as a rheostat in order to adjust the 40µs timeout to be as close as you want it to be.